# Publishing a blog with hexo gives me a a barebones site, why does it not look the same as when I run `hexo server`

Tags: hexo

I made a blog with `hexo` and wrote an article in markdown. I ran `hexo server` and saw the changes on localhost:4000, but when I ran `hexo generate` and tried to open the `index.html` file in the `public/` folder, it appeared completely barebones

Isn't the `publish` folder supposed to resemble the `localhost:4000` site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps to make it work:

As stated in the [docs](https://hexo.io/), run these commands to start a new blog:

```
$ npm install hexo-cli -g
$ hexo init blog
$ cd blog
$ npm install
$ hexo server
```

At this point your site will be running with the dev server.

Now shut down the dev server and use

```
$ hexo generate
```

to generate the source files (in the `/public` folder)

At this point, if you simply open the index.html in Chrome (or any other browser), it won't work because the paths to the external resources are broken.

**You need to host the files on a web server of some sort**. If you don't already have apache running somewhere on your machine, here is a quick way to run a node static web server:

```
$ npm -g install static-server
```

will install [a simple http server to serve static resource files from a local directory](https://github.com/nbluis/static-server).

then navigate to your public folder:

```
$ cd public
```

and start off the web server:

```
$ static-server
```

Open your browser at `http://localhost:9080` and your site should be up and running.

Comment: My bad, I did run `hexo generate`, but I put publish in the title. Edited the question just now to reflect that

Comment: yes then it should look the same. Did you check that the files inside the `public` folder were actually modified ?

Comment: Yeah, the files are modified, I can actually see the post that I made, but it looks like the phase only contains html and no css or js

Comment: page* not phase

Comment: ok that's really weird, not sure how to help. Maybe just start again and follow all the steps on the official docs ...

Comment: I think I have found the issue, but am unable to resolve it. The website that is generated has many broken links. 

In the Chrome console it has a lot of `FILE NOT FOUND` errors. Is there a setting somewhere that I can change to fix this?

Comment: eg it says /css/style.css NOT FOUND. My config.yml is default, I haven't changed anything there

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided has the site in a subdirectory, not in the root directory. In your `config.yaml` file you will see a parameter for both `url` and `root` that you need to set to reflect your live site.